# Simple Map Application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to make a map app of a building.

Here is how it should work: user picks a room from the picker view, presses OK and it should put a dot on the map where that room is.

What would be the easiest way to do it? How can I make the picker on a separate page (like in the alarm page - you press the "+" and it shows the picker for the time) so it then shows the dot on the certain room on the buildings plan?

Comment: easiest way? odesk probably...

Answer (score 1):

In the Clock application where you set an Alarm, clicking the "+" presents a modal view controller. You can tell because it slides onto the screen from the bottom.

You have two distinct controllers, for two distinct views. The main controller sets itself as the target for the "+" button, then when its action is invoked it simply does:

```
[self presentViewController:theOtherController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Once the user has finished doing something on that modal view, you can issue:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Read more about that here.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html